# Devexpress Master detail grid control

Tags: winforms, devexpress

Winform application.

Is it possible to have devexpress master-detail grid control  in winforms where the **master and detail grid** have **no relation** between them??

In **web application** devexpress detal grid doesn't require a relation between the master grid.

So is this possible in **Winforms** application???

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible.  Please refer to the following topic in DevExpress documentation in this regard:

[Binding to Data Specifics](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3508)